# Meaning of error message "There has been an IO error: error 2038" in SDL Media Manager

Tags: media-manager

I have a client using SDL Media Manager.

When she logs into the Media Manager GUI, and she uploads a video, she gets the following error message as a modal window:

"There has been an I/O Error: Error #2038".

Could someone advise what this error means, or point me to a resource that gives a definition of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error sounds like an issue with the upload on the backend, I'm seeing several reports on the net with the same error on different applications.

So in this case I think it is best to have your client contact Customer Support about the issue and supply the details around the error:

- What browser are you using
- How large is the file you are uploading
- Do smaller files work, or does every upload fail
- Does it work for other users/with other browsers

Comment: We couldn't get a root cause, but what we found is that the error only occurs when the client is on-site and logged on to their VPN. It appears as though this is caused...somehow, by the client's firewall. The same client could upload the same video off of the VPN without issue.

Answer (score 1):

The file uploader is a Flash component which sometimes indeed gives vague error messages. I am not familiar with this exact code but it could be something like a to big file, timeout, network connection issue etc.

You could try to troubleshoot it by uploading a different file (smaller or other file type), upload from a different PC or use a different browser.

EDIT: added timeout to the list of probable causes.